# Gatsby 5 Image Sharp errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, sharp

I have a Gatsby v5 project using typescript that fails to compile and display just using the initial `gatsby new` command.
It does not compile and gives the following errors:

```
load plugins
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/work/Desktop/website/project_file/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/work/Desktop/website/project_file/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

[1]    32594 killed     gatsby develop
```

If I comment out the following plugins:

```
'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
```

in the `gatsby-config.ts` and run `gatsby develop` the boilerplate for the base application displays but I receive a list of the following errors in the console:

```
Error 623: GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown type "ImgixFluid".
    at undefined:2:47
```

```
Error 612: GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown type "ImageSharpFluid".
    at undefined:2:58
```

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Made a github issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/37294

Answer (score 0):

After following the github issue posted in the comment by FloofyDoug and using the work around provided, I discovered that Gatbsy 5 and as such the plugins for Image Sharp et al are not compatible with my current OS (OSX 10.15 Catalina) and would need an upgrade to Big Sur or higher. The work around is just to use an older version of Gatsby.

Comment: this can't be the case because I am able to run gatsby v5 projects with mojave. Only now after UPG

Comment: How could you achieve that, any details possible?